# xyplot legend configuration

Tags: r, plot, lattice, legend-properties

It's my first time in here, so I hope not to do it wrong.

I have a database of different measures of wood moisture content in different species as well as various index. These measures have been taken every two hours for six months.

I'm trying to make a script that can be used in different locations. So far I managed to make the graph look ok, but with the legend I'm stuck.
To make the axis I had to combine line date and hour, because I only wanted the ticks every Friday at 00:00.

My problems appeared when I tried to make custom lines with specific colors and different shapes and then tried to make the legend. The colors don’t match the graph because I have changed the colors, but they are not changed in the legend. I also changed the order of the names that appear in the legend but the colors are still the default ones and don’t change with the name. When I try to do it manually with key, the line colors are always black, and also none is dotted.

I have corrected the plot in paint, yes really shameful, but I needed to deliver it. But I need to do it more times so I’m trying to find a final solution. I have found that there is a bug in a post, and propose a manual way, but I’m not sure I can do it that way… so if any one knows how can I do it in a simpler way.

So far my tries have been:

a)  The default colors and organization

```
grafico_juan <- read.table("C:/Users/JFG/Desktop/graf_juan2.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", na.strings="NA",dec=",", strip.white=TRUE)
library(relimp, pos=14)
library(lattice, pos=15)
library(grid, pos=15)
str(grafico_juan)
grafico_juan[, "Date"] <- as.Date(as.character(grafico_juan[, "Date"]), format = "%d.%m.%y")
str(grafico_juan)
grafico_juan[, "D.T"] <- as.POSIXct(grafico_juan$D.T, format = "%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S")
str(grafico_juan)

day=format(grafico_juan$D.T,"%a")
data.frame(grafico_juan,day)
#para seleccionar la parte que me hace falta para los puntos y las líneas
grafico_juan2<-subset(grafico_juan, subset = (Time == "00:00:00") & (day == "vie"), selct= Date:PRMMTC)
grafico_juan3<-subset(grafico_juan, subset = (Time =="00:00:00"),select = Date:PRMMTC)
data.frame(grafico_juan)
str(grafico_juan2)
str(grafico_juan3)
xyplot(CSC + EUC + PCC + PLC + PRC + PRMMTC + PSC ~ D.T, type="l", cex=1, xaxt="n", auto.key=list(space="top",border=TRUE, columns=7, lines= T, points = F), par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(lwd=2)), scales=list(x=list(at=grafico_juan2$D.T, labels=format(grafico_juan2$D.T,"%d/%m"),rot=0, cex = 1, relation='free'), y=list(at= seq(from=2,to=nrow(grafico_juan), by=1),tick.number=52, rot=0, cex = 1, relation='free')), abline = list(h = 3:60, v = grafico_juan2$D.T, col = "grey"), data=grafico_juan, xlab="DATE (dd/mm)", ylab="MC (%)")
```

b)  Changing order and color

```
xyplot(CSC + EUC + PCC + PLC + PRC + PRMMTC + PSC ~ D.T, 
  type="l",col=c("green", "turquoise" ,"blue" , "green4", "deeppink",
  "black","red"),lty=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,3), cex=3, xaxt="n", 
  auto.key=list(space="top",border=TRUE, columns=7, lines= T,
  points = F, text=c("PL", "PS", "PR", "PC", "PRMMT", "CS", "EU")), 
  par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(lwd=2)), 
  scales=list(x=list(at=grafico_juan2$D.T, 
  labels=format(grafico_juan2$D.T,"%d/%m"),rot=0, cex = 1, 
  relation='free'), y=list(at= seq(from=2,to=nrow(grafico_juan), 
  by=1),tick.number=52, rot=0, cex = 1, relation='free')),
  abline = list(h = 3:60, v = grafico_juan2$D.T, col = c("grey")), 
  data=grafico_juan, xlab="DATE (dd/mm)", ylab="MC (%)")
```

[image]

c)  Doing it as a as.layer and using key insted of auto.key I still have the same problem, because it doesn't colour the lines nor put one dotted.

```
a<-xyplot(CSC + EUC + PCC + PLC + PRC + PRMMTC + PSC ~ D.T, type="", cex=3, xaxt="n", key= list(text=list(levels=c("PL", "PS", "PR", "PC", "PRMMT", "CS", "EU")), lines= TRUE, border=TRUE, columns=7, fill=c("green4", "red", "deeppink","blue",  "black", "green", "turquoise")) , par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(lwd=2)), scales=list(x=list(at=grafico_juan2$D.T, labels=format(grafico_juan2$D.T,"%d/%m"),rot=0, cex = 1, relation='free'), y=list(at= seq(from=2,to=nrow(grafico_juan), by=1),tick.number=52, rot=0, cex = 1, relation='free')), abline = list(h = 3:60, v = grafico_juan2$D.T, col = c("grey")), data=grafico_juan, xlab="DATE (dd/mm)", ylab="MC (%)")

b<-xyplot(PLC ~ D.T, type="l",col= "green4" , cex=1, xaxt="n", auto.key=FALSE, par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(lwd=2)), data=grafico_juan, xlab="", ylab="")
c<-xyplot(PSC ~ D.T, type="l",col= "red" , cex=1, xaxt="n", auto.key=FALSE, par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(lwd=2)), data=grafico_juan, xlab="", ylab="")
d<-xyplot(PRC ~ D.T, type="l",col= "deeppink" , cex=1, xaxt="n", auto.key=FALSE, par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(lwd=2)), data=grafico_juan, xlab="", ylab="")
e<-xyplot(PCC ~ D.T, type="l",col= "blue" , cex=1, xaxt="n", auto.key=FALSE, par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(lwd=2)), data=grafico_juan, xlab="", ylab="")
f<-xyplot(PRMMTC ~ D.T, type="l",col= "black" , cex=1, xaxt="n", auto.key=FALSE, par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(lwd=2)), data=grafico_juan, xlab="", ylab="")
g<-xyplot(CSC ~ D.T, type="l" ,col= "green", cex=1, xaxt="n", auto.key=FALSE, par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(lwd=2)), data=grafico_juan, xlab="", ylab="")
h<-xyplot(EUC ~ D.T, type="l",col= "turquoise" , lty=3 ,cex=1, xaxt="n", auto.key=FALSE, par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(lwd=2)), data=grafico_juan, xlab="", ylab="")
library(latticeExtra)
a + as.layer(b) + as.layer(c) + as.layer(d) + as.layer(e) + as.layer(f)  + as.layer(g) + as.layer(h)
```

[image]

The ideal one should be like this last picture but with the correct legend.

Not sure if you need the data, but I provide part of it because I can't put too many characters, `D.T` is column `Date` and column `Time` in the same column.

```
Date            Time           D.T         EUC     PLC  PCC PSC PRC CSC PRMMTC
12.03.15     14:00:00   12.03.15  14:00:00  11      9,3 6,8 9,1 9,6 3   6
12.03.15     16:00:00   12.03.15  16:00:00  11,2    9,3 6,6 9,2 9,2 8,9 6,6
12.03.15     18:00:00   12.03.15  18:00:00  11,7    9,7 6,6 9,6 9,6 9,2 7,4
12.03.15     20:00:00   12.03.15  20:00:00  11,6    9,6 6,5 9,6 9,5 9,1 7,6
12.03.15     22:00:00   12.03.15  22:00:00  11,6    9,6 6,5 9,6 9,6 9,1 7,6
13.03.15     00:00:00   13.03.15  00:00:00  11,7    9,7 6,6 9,6 9,6 9,2 7,7
13.03.15     02:00:00   13.03.15  02:00:00  11,8    9,8 6,6 9,6 9,6 9,2 7,7
13.03.15     04:00:00   13.03.15  04:00:00  11,7    9,8 6,6 9,6 9,8 9,2 7,7
13.03.15     06:00:00   13.03.15  06:00:00  11,7    9,7 6,6 9,7 9,7 9,2 7,7
13.03.15     08:00:00   13.03.15  08:00:00  11,9    9,8 6,7 9,8 10  9,3 7,9
13.03.15     10:00:00   13.03.15  10:00:00  11,7    9,8 6,6 9,8 9,8 9,2 7,7
13.03.15     12:00:00   13.03.15  12:00:00  11,7    9,9 6,9 9,9 10  9,3 7,7
13.03.15     14:00:00   13.03.15  14:00:00  11,9    10  6,9 9,9 10,1 9,4 7,7
13.03.15     16:00:00   13.03.15  16:00:00  11,8    10  6,9 10  10,2 9,3 8
```

Comment: I founded this guy with the same problem http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/9107_6b2dc3a4ca404a689c0b47ec781149af.html